# Using wire or reg with input or output

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

When you declare something as input or output, how do you know if you have to also declare it as a `reg` or a `wire`?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`reg` and `wire` specify how the object will be assigned and are therefore only meaningful for outputs.

If you plan to assign your output in sequential code,such as within an `always` block, declare it as a `reg` (which really is a misnomer for "variable" in Verilog). Otherwise, it should be a `wire`, which is also the default.

Comment: If you add `\`default_nettype none` you will get an error if u don't explicitly specify wire.

Comment: Will the `reg` declaration make any difference to outside connected modules ?

Answer (score 28):

An `output reg foo` is just shorthand for `output foo_wire; reg foo; assign foo_wire = foo`.  It's handy when you plan to register that output anyway.  I don't think `input reg` is meaningful for `module` (perhaps `task`).  `input wire` and `output wire` are the same as `input` and `output`: it's just more explicit.

Answer (score 7):

The Verilog code compiler you use will dictate what you *have* to do. If you use illegal syntax, you will get a compile error.

An `output` must also be declared as a `reg` only if it is assigned using a "procedural assignment".  For example:

```
output reg a;
always @* a = b;
```

There is no need to declare an `output` as a `wire`.

There is no need to declare an `input` as a `wire` or `reg`.

Answer (score 5):

seeing it in digital circuit domain

1. A Wire will create a wire output which can only be assigned any input by using assign statement as assign statement creates a port/pin connection and wire can be joined to the port/pin
2. A reg will create a register(D FLIP FLOP ) which gets or recieve inputs on basis of sensitivity list either it can be clock (rising or falling ) or combinational edge .

so it completely depends on your use whether you need to create a register and tick it according to sensitivity list or you want to create a port/pin assignment

Comment: A mux can be inferred using `reg` variables, without using flip flops

Answer (score 3):

basically reg is used to store values.For example if you want a counter(which will count and thus will have some value for each count),we will use a reg.
On the other hand,if we just have a plain signal with 2 values 0 and 1,we will declare it as wire.Wire can't hold values.So assigning values to wire leads to problems....