# Verilog Error: Object on left-hand side of assignment must have a variable data type

Tags: verilog, intel-fpga

I'm trying to write a top-level module in Verilog that will open a water valve whenever a sensor reads values below a certain number.

Here is my code:

```
module ProjectDSD(alteraClock, sensorInput, openValve);

input sensorInput, alteraClock;
output openValve;

always @(sensorInput)
begin

if(sensorInput < 100)       //sensor value to irrigate at
begin

openValve <= 1;  //here

end

else
begin

openValve <= 0;  //here

end
end    
endmodule
```

Im getting an error saying:

> Object "openValve" on left-hand side of assignment must have a variable data type

What am I missing? Also, which pins can I use on an Altera DE2-155 board to output a digital signal of only 1's and 0's for the the valve to open/close?

Answer (score 5):

s/output openValve/output reg openValve/

Outputs default to `wire`; you need a `reg`. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33485197/why-do-we-use-reg-in-fgpa-vhdl-vivado/33504420#33504420) question.

Answer (score 1):

`openValve` is currently inferred as a `wire`. Add `reg openValve;` below `output openValve;` and your code will work.

---

Suggestions: It looks like you are following the IEEE1364-1995 non-ANSI coding style. Will still legal, you might want to change to the ANSI coding style, supported in IEEE1364-2001 and above.

Non-ANSI:

```
module ProjectDSD(alteraClock, sensorInput, openValve);

input sensorInput, alteraClock;
output openValve;
reg openValve;
```

ANSI:

```
module ProjectDSD(
  input alteraClock, sensorInput,
  output reg openValve);
```

For combinational blocks, it is recommended to use `always @*` (or the synonymous `always @(*)`) instead of `always @(sensorInput)`. `@*` is an auto sensitivity list also added in IEEE1364-2001

Answer (score 0):

Try `output reg openValve;`.

For the second half of your question (which should really be a separate question) [import this QSF file](ftp://ftp.altera.com/up/pub/Altera_Material/Boards/DE2-115/DE2_115.qsf) into your project. Any of the GPIO can be configured as outputs, and are accessible by the 40-pin header on the side.

Comment: That is not valid syntax according to any IEEE1364 or IEEE1800. Some tools allow it but it is a bad practice. I explained it on another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33747519/1959732)

Comment: Fair point, my bad. I (almost) always write ANSI, so I missed that the OP wasn't.

Comment: Hi Greg - I can't find anything in 1364-2005 which would make this code (or mine) invalid. In fact, 12.3.3 explicitly allows it - note "in the body of the module", and the `output reg` production. The confusion may be due to the text at the bottom of 12.3.3, which states that if the decl doesn't include a net or variable type, then it can be declared again in a net or variable decl, and the example on p175 shows this.

Comment: And on the issue of "ANSI": the word ANSI doesn't appear in this context in 1364. It is a misnomer; various authors (incorrectly) thought that the new style was how things were done in "ANSI C", but they were wrong. You can't specify lists of objects in C in this context.