# register initial values at testbench

Tags: verilog

want to send an initial value to reg div_num_tb (it's a 8 bit register)
and i get this error:

> Error (10137): Verilog HDL Procedural Assignment error at top_tb.v(23): object "div_num_tb" on left-hand side of assignment must have a variable data type

other single bit registers doesn't do issues

```
module top_tb();
  reg clock_tb, reset_tb, enable_tb; 
  reg [7:0]Div_num_tb;
  wire Out_signal_tb; 
  wire [7:0]count_tb;`

Top U0(
  .clock (clock_tb),
  .reset (reset_tb),
  .enable (enable_tb),
  .Div_num (div_num_tb),
  .Div_num (Div_num_tb),
  .Out_signal (Out_signal_tb),
  .count (count_tb)
);

initial
begin   
  clock_tb = 0;
  reset_tb = 1;
  enable_tb = 0;
  div_num_tb = 8'b00000000;
end
endmodule
```

> Error (10137): Verilog HDL Procedural Assignment error at top_tb.v(23): object "div_num_tb" on left-hand side of assignment must have a variable data type

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Verilog Error: Object on left-hand side of assignment must have a variable data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34028900/verilog-error-object-on-left-hand-side-of-assignment-must-have-a-variable-data)

Comment: @Qui - this is not a dupe. In the question you reference, the assignment is to a module port that defaults to a wire; in this question, the assignment is to an undeclared object, which unfortunately also defaults to a wire.

Comment: Add a "`default_netype none" to your description to avoid your typos turning into wires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Div_num_tb` has been defined as a `reg`.

`reg [7:0]Div_num_tb;`

but not `div_num_tb`, which as a result, is being inferred as a wire.  Verilog is case-sensitive.